# Parse.com Storing/Retrieving all push notifications sent so far

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I wish to get all push notifications sent from server with Parse.com APIs. Is there any way by which I can get all these using some query, Or I can put some cloud hook by which i can store these notifications to some cloud table and then query on the client ?

Comment: Did you find any answer ?

Comment: @Mutawe No Couldn't find any way to achieve this, But instead used a workaround. What I did was to create a table called `Push` in database and used cloud code to generate a push notification everytime data is entered in table.